# How do I add table row dynamically in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, rendering, react-bootstrap

I am currently making a tax calculator app with React and I want to add multiple rows to a table depending on the duration the user selects from the input of type range. Each row will be showing the dates of repayment and corresponding values calculated by the amount of loan that the user wants to get as well as the interest rate. I am currently using bootstrap v5 with React.

My idea was that when the duration gets set by the user, I make a function to make an array of dates and map it through. However, the concern I have with that is that if the user then changes the duration will the table add or remove row based upon the change?

Comment: yes, you can save the data as a ```state``` with array type, and render the data with ```array.map```

Comment: I tried making a function called getArrOfDates() with setDates[...date, d] inside a for loop for the duration and used it to return dates. Then I mapped through with getArrOfDates.map(d => ...) and showed me an error "Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `useEffect` hook to create an array of dates each time the user changes the duration value. Then you can simply map through this array to display the number of rows required.

This means that you don't need to set the "today" date because it will be setup in this useEffect hook which also runs before the first render.

The final code should look something like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
    const [loan, setLoan] = useState(1000);
    const [duration, setDuration] = useState(1);
    const [interest, setInterest] = useState(0);
    const [dates, setDates] = useState([]);

    const getInterest = () => {
        let interestedAmount = (loan * interest) / 100;
        interestedAmount /= duration;
        return Math.round((interestedAmount + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
    };

    const getPrincipal = () => {
        let dividedAmount = loan / duration;
        return Math.round((dividedAmount + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
    };

    const getTotalRepayment = () => {
        return getInterest() + getPrincipal();
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        let datesArray = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < duration; i++) {
            let date = new Date();
            date = new Date(date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + i));
            datesArray.push(
                date.getDate() + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getFullYear()
            );
        }

        setDates(datesArray);
    }, [duration]);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <header>
                <h1>Your Loan</h1>
            </header>
            <main>
                <form>
                    <div className='row g-3 align-items-center'>
                        <div className='col-auto'>
                            <label htmlFor='loan-input' className='form-label'>
                                Loan Amount (£) : {loan}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div className='col-auto'>
                            <input
                                type='range'
                                value={loan}
                                min='1000'
                                max='200000'
                                step='1000'
                                className='form-range'
                                id='loan-input'
                                onChange={(e) => setLoan(e.target.value)}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='row g-3 align-items-center'>
                        <div className='col-auto'>
                            <label htmlFor='duration-input' className='form-label'>
                                Duration (in Months) : {duration}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div className='col-auto'>
                            <input
                                type='range'
                                value={duration}
                                min='1'
                                max='60'
                                step='1'
                                className='form-range'
                                id='duration-input'
                                onChange={(e) => setDuration(e.target.value)}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div className='row g-3 align-items-center'>
                    <div className='col-auto'>
                        <label htmlFor='interest-range' className='form-label'>
                            Interest Rate (%) : {interest}
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div className='col-auto'>
                        <input
                            type='range'
                            value={interest}
                            min='0'
                            max='10'
                            step='1'
                            className='form-range'
                            id='interest-range'
                            onChange={(e) => setInterest(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <table className='table'>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope='col'>Repayment Date</th>
                                <th scope='col'>Principal</th>
                                <th scope='col'>Interest</th>
                                <th scope='col'>Total Repayment</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {dates.map((date, index) => (
                                <tr key={index}>
                                    <td>{date}</td>
                                    <td>{getPrincipal()}</td>
                                    <td>{getInterest()}</td>
                                    <td>{getTotalRepayment()}</td>
                                </tr>
                            ))}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </main>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You probably would want to add a +1 in that for loop (when the new date gets created) because it wouldn't make sense to pay back the loan on the day it is taken... 

date = new Date(date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1 + i));